# Scope issues with pgfplotstable

Tags: pgfplotstable, scoping

I created a command that creates a table and do some computations on it.
And I would like to use this command several times.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableset{%
    create on use/tmp/.style={create col/set={2}}}%
\newcommand\createonecol[1]{%
  \pgfplotstablenew[columns={tmp}]{6}{\data}
  \pgfplotstabletranspose{#1}{\data}
}
\begin{document}
\createonecol{\dataA}
\createonecol{\dataB}
\end{document}
```

The problem is the following one: the second time I call `\createonecol`, the table in `\data` is not created, thus `pgfplotstabletranspose` fails.

If I put curly braces around each call to `\createonecol`, there is no problem. However I don't want to scope them since I want to access both `dataA` and `dataB` at the same time.

Comment: could you provide a full minimal example, i.e. with `\dataA` and `\dataB` set. That will make it a lot easier for others to help.